# adding number of days in calendar extender

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, calendarextender

I have been working on a project and I got stuck with a problem i.e I am able to select first and last date using asp.net calendar control but i want it to be done with calendar extender

the code shown as below is for calender control ..please provide me the solution for calendar extender with required modification..............

```
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    Calendar1.SelectionMode = CalendarSelectionMode.DayWeek;
    //ArrayList selectedDates = new ArrayList();
    string s = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    DateTime today = DateTime.Parse(s);
    DateTime firstDay = today.AddDays(-(double)(today.DayOfWeek));
    DateTime lastDay = today.AddDays(6 - (double)(today.DayOfWeek));
    for (int loop = 0; loop < 7; loop++)
        Calendar1.SelectedDates.Add(firstDay.AddDays(loop));
    lblStartOfWeek.Text = firstDay.ToLongDateString();
    lblEndOfWeek.Text = lastDay.ToLongDateString();
    lblStartOfWeek.Visible = true;
    lblEndOfWeek.Visible = true;
    checkLessonPlan();
   }
```

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has said it yet but "Please provide me the solution" is a phrase that turns a lot of people off. Show what you have tried and how it has failed. Make it clear where your problem is. At the moment you are just saying you want something but with no indication you have tried to do it yourself so people are not going to be interested in helping. Narrow down where you are having problems and ask a more specific question.

Comment: As you didn't mentioned what exactly problem do you No one can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected void Calendar1_ontextchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string numberofdays=   Convert.ToDateTime(this.TextBox1.Text).DayOfWeek.ToString("d");
    DateTime select = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);
    lblStartOfWeek.Text = select.AddDays(-Convert.ToInt32(numberofdays)).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
    lblEndOfWeek.Text = select.AddDays(6-Convert.ToInt32(numberofdays)).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");


}
```